# Do readable streams always close

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote code to inject data into a stream when a certain tag or set of characters is found. If I'm reading a chunk character by character from a readable stream, and I find a partial match at the end of the chunk, I will need to save that data and prepend it to the next chunk. But to do that I am also relying on `readable.on('end')`. Are there any stream types (ie TCP?) that stay open indefinitely, and that I could be waiting to prepend to a chunk that will never arrive?

Right now I am testing using a readable stream that reads a file, so it's definitely going to 'close' at some point. But I like to over-design my code, so, what if the stream remains open?

Comment: Certainly one could construct a readable stream that stayed open, but didn't flow any data.  There's nothing in the stream architecture that prevents that.  Can you perhaps turn this into a real problem with real streams of a particular type so we can help you with your actual problem?